# How to calculate angle between two 2D matrix transform?

Tags: c#, math, matrix

I have two 2D objects and each one has a transform matrix in C#.
in fact one of these gets from rotation of the other one.
How can I calculate the angle between these two matrix?
Is there any method that can do it directly?

Comment: A matrix isn't rotated it *is* the transformation, you could probably compare matrix elements but I don't think this is what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 2D angle transform rotating through an angle θ will look like this:

```
    | cos(&theta;)   -sin(&theta;)     0 | 
T = | sin(&theta;)    cos(&theta;)     0 | 
    | 0               0                1 |
```

If you multiply your two transformation matricies together you'll get another one that's of the same form.  It should be easy to calculate the angle.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how matrix is stored, but *usually* it's stored in "column based" order, which means

```
 XAxis_x  YAxis_x   Offset_x
 XAxis_y  YAxis_y   Offset_y
 0        0         1
```

So if you get `XAxis` like a vector from one matrix and `XAxis` from another, you can measure angle between those 2 vectors. After measure  in the same way an angle between `YAxises` of both matrices.  So at the end you will have 2 angles: `Rx`, `Ry`, which applying on *first* matrix, will generated you the *second* one.